Magento 2.4.7 Cart Page Not Showing Estimate Shipping Tax and Summary Block
After Upgrade my store to Magento 2.4.7 ,
on my cart page the Estimate Shipping Tax block is not rendering and also
the Order Summary is not rendering.
console keep showing this error :
cookieMessagesObservable is not defined

can anyone help me about this ?

https://www.hulkapps.com/blogs/ecommerce-hub/navigating-common-magento-2-4-7-update-issues-solutions-for-developers#:~:text=What%20causes%20the%20%22cookieMessagesObservable%20is,code%2C%20or%20outdated%20cached%20data. check this link for your reference
